# Component identification, Trascend SSD340

Tags: identification, components, ssd

i have a broken SSD, one component burned up because of the power source of the computer and I can't identify it in order to get a new one and fix the SSD, the component is U23 in the picture. The three left pins are connected to 5V, the middle one of the right is COM, the top one is, maybe, not connected. I think it's a voltage regulator, but im not sure.

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1) What makes you think that part has failed?  Going by the photo it looks fine.  2) Can you post a better photo?  The one you provided is very low-res and grainy (more light would help).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I found the photo that i posted on the internet, is the same ssd. The original part is completely burned up, i cant see anything on it. The picture that i posted is from this web https://3c.3dmgame.com/show-52-3138-2.html, this one https://3c.3dmgame.com/uploadfile/2016/0426/20160426111145528.jpg